# Finding associated primes of quotient modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Consider the ideal $I=(a)\cap(a,b)^2=(a^2,ab)$ in $k[a,b]$ and set $R=k[a,b]/I$. The problem is to show that for all $n\ge 1$ and all $\lambda\ne 0$, the ideals $(b^n)$ and $(a+\lambda b^n)$ of $R$ are $(a,b)$-primary in $R$. This amounts to saying that the set of associated primes of the quotient $k[a,b]$-modules $R/(b^n)$ and $R/(a+\lambda b^n)$ is the singleton consisting of the ideal $(a,b)\subset k[a,b]$.

First, it would be reasonable to find "simpler" $k[a,b]$-modules isomorphic to $R/(b^n)$ and $R/(a+\lambda b^n)$, but I'm not sure how to do that. I don't see how one can apply any of the isomorphism theorems, for example. It is plausible to think that $R/(a+\lambda b^n)\simeq k[b]/(b^{n+1})$ since $b^{n+1}=b(b^n)=b(-a/\lambda)=-(ab)/\lambda=0$ in the quotient, but I don't see how to prove this formally.

Even if I do know that last isomorphism, I'm not sure how to find $\operatorname{Ass}$ of that module.

---

Added:

According to the hint in the answers, $R/(b^n)\simeq k[a,b]/(a^2,ab,b^n)$, and according to my conjecture, $R/(a+\lambda b^n)\simeq R[b]/(b^{n+1})$. Now $(a,b)$ is an associated prime of each of the quotient modules because  $k[a,b]/(a,b)$ injects into them (added later: is that true at all? Originally I thought that this is true because $k[a,b]/(a,b)\simeq k$ and any ring homomorphism from a field to a ring is injective. But here we are dealing with module homomorphisms...). According to Theorem 3.10 from Eisenbud, to show that $(a,b)$ is the only associated prime of those quotient modules, it suffices to show that the $k[a,b]$-submodule $(a)$ of $R$  is also $(a,b)$-primary in $R$ and

$$(0)=(a)\cap (b^n)\\ (0)=(a)\cap (a+\lambda b^n)$$

are *minimal* primary decompositions.

Well, if there is a smaller primary decomposition, then $(0)$ is a primary ideal of $R$. But I don't see what it contradicts too. Also, to prove that $(a)$ is $(a,b)$ primary, we need to show (as above) that $k[a,b]/(a,b)$ injects into $R/(a)$. Here I have the same question as with the other injections above.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Variables, I suppose. (Since there is the ring $k[a,b]$ in the background.)

Comment: It might be a $k$-algebra generated by $a$ and $b$, without $a,b$ being indeterminates.

Comment: The source (https://books.google.com/books?id=Fm_yPgZBucMC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=eisenbud+exercise+3.10&source=bl&ots=7Dm2EDO2Ng&sig=ACfU3U0BVJ3OMnZYZbmXr1a8yLTV-NWMHg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJzq2bqYXhAhVDpoMKHYR1CGYQ6AEwA3oECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false p.112) doesn't actually specify that.

Comment: Your conjecture is wrong, consider the element $a+b^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Whether *a,b* denote  indeterminates or not, one has the isomorphism:
\begin{align}R/(b^n)&=k[a,b]/(a^2,ab)\bigm/b^n\!\cdot k[a,b]/(a^2,ab)=k[a,b]/(a^2,ab)\!\Bigm/\!(b^n,a^2, ab)/(a^2,ab)\\
&\simeq k[a,b]/(b^n,a^2, ab)\;\qquad\text{ (3rd isomorphism theorem)}
\end{align}

Comment: I've edited my question and included some progress and doubts.

Comment: $\operatorname{Ass}R/b^n)$  contains a single element because $\operatorname{Spec} R/(b^n)$ contains a single element – namely,$(a,b)/(a^2,ab,b^n)$.

Comment: I'm not sure what Ass has to do with $\text{Spec} R/(b^n)$. An element of Ass is a prime ideal in $k[x,y]$.

Comment: @user437309: $\operatorname{Ass}R/(b^n)\subset \operatorname{Supp}R/(b^n)$ as a $k[a,b]$-module. The latter corresponds bijectively to the prime ideals of $R/(b^n)$ – in terms of Zariski topology, it is $V((a^2,ab, b^n))$.